# Date Range filter not working in custom Grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent

I have created the custom sales report using ui component.

Grid is loading correctly. I have added the date range filter as like below.

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Here is the screenshot of error.

[image]

In the filter section when the from and To date selected and applied,
I am getting Bad request error.

This is the error in Request

```
  {error: "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception", errorcode: "23000" }
```

error: "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception"
errorcode: "23000"

Can anyone check where i am wrong and help me to resolve this error. The answers provided below all i tried but no solution for it.

**Update:**

Complete code of my listing file

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<!-- Integration -->
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- we define a provider -->
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing_data_source</item>
        <!-- same string as above -->
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>

    <!-- define column type -->
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_columns</item>

</argument>
<!-- Data source -->
<dataSource name="catalogreport_manage_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ManageGridDataProvider</argument> <!-- Data provider class -->
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing_data_source</argument> <!-- provider defined above -->
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument> <!-- Primary key -->
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument> <!-- URL name parameter -->

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- Primary key column name -->
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">item_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<!-- Container Listing Top -->
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Button to manage views -->
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                    <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">jobs_department_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <!-- Button to manage columns -->
    <container name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>


    <!-- Filters -->
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Department ID Filter -->

        <!-- Department name Filter -->
        <!--  <filterInput name="sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item> 
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item> 
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterInput> -->
    </filters>

      <!-- Paging -->
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>


    <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">catalogreport/export/gridToCsv</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">catalogreport/export/gridToXml</item>
                        <!-- <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="string">true</item>    -->
                    </item> 
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>

</container>


<!-- Columns -->
<columns name="catalogreport_manage_columns">
    <!-- <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <settings>
            <indexField>item_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>  -->
    <!-- Name Column -->


    <column name="increment_id" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order number</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
     <column name="sku">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item> 
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>


    <!-- new code -->
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                </item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY</item> //set date format as per your requirement
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <!-- new code -->
    <column name="status" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="name" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="qty_ordered" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quantity</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="shipping_amount" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping amount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="discount_code" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="discount_amount" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="price" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="row_total" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row total</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="grand_total" class="Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quantity">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand total</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>



</columns>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share the screenshot of error?

Comment: @MohitRane, added the error screenshot, pls have a look

Comment: check removing `<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>` this code and check if everything is working

Comment: @MohitRane, No same error after that also, cleared cache and checked it

Comment: check the exception log

Comment: @MohitRane, yes this is in exception, Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous at

Comment: do you have column `created_at` column in your table/ InstallSchema.php ?

Comment: @MohitRane, I am not using custom table, using sales_order_item table for loading collection

Comment: Please refer this link it will help you **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405483/magento-issue-with-external-mod-integrity-constraint-violation-1052-column-cr**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95716/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mohit-rane).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95717/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mohit-rane).

Comment: @MohitRane, pls check the chat

Comment: @jafarpinjar have you got the solution ?

Comment: @aravind, No not yet, looking for solution for it

Comment: @RohanHapani, Its a custom grid

Comment: @RohanHapani, After commenting created_at column, grid is loading fine

Comment: what's your created_at data type in your database?

Comment: Timestamp it is

Comment: hi @Karthik, date sort is not working, its throwing the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please replace your code with below given code for Date Field(created_at) only.

```
<column name="created_at">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Update your *Twofoursevencommerce\Catalogreport\Model\Resource\Products\Collection.php* file. And Add below given code in the *_initSelect()* method before *return $this*.

```
$this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
```

And then just flush the caches and refresh your grid page.

Comment: This code i tried but not worked..

Comment: May I know the version of your Magento2?

Comment: version is 2.2.2

Comment: Hello @karthik, is there any possibility to add the customer address to grid, at least country?

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, It is possible but there are 2 address types (Billing and Shipping) and you will have to confirm which address you want to show over there.

Comment: hello @Karthik, I want to load shipping address there, I am able to retrieve there, its now working

Comment: Great.. Can you share how did you implement it? I have also implemented it. If you need the code then I will share with you.

Comment: I did using prepareDataSource from loading the orderid, i used custom query to get the shipping address.

Comment: Please enable the chat... Let me give you better solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96589/discussion-between-kartik-maniyar-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: pls check the chat..@karthik

Comment: This is working well but one issue, after date range filter and export, its exporting all data instead of filtered data, can you please update me on this

Comment: hi @Kartik, i tried changing code in my listing.xml file to mui that's not working for me

Comment: hi @kartik, pls check the chat..

Comment: How can we add payment method to the grid?

Comment: There is separate table 'sales_order_payment' for the same... You should look into it.

Comment: yes, i made it work, how can we show invoice number there? which table i need to refer to show invoice number?

Comment: 'sales_invoice' table.

Comment: hi Kartik, I am already showing order increment id, the field_name in invoice table also is same, I need to show invoice id also, how can i show both order inc_id and invoice inc_id?

Comment: Hi Kartik, this is showing individual shipping amount for each order item in a single order, can we show only one shipping amount for entire order?

Answer (score 2):

> **Try This :-**

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY</item> //set date format as per your requirement
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: hi @RkRathod, After adding these lines, it is not showing any filter option to filter

Comment: follow command s:s:d or clean chache

Comment: Yes, I run those commands @Rathod..

Comment: i m already do this in sales order grid using this code

Comment: please attch full code of this file

Comment: I have updated my full code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96206/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: can we add payment method to the grid?

Comment: Hello @Rathod, how can we show payment method used for the order in the grid?

Comment: let me check....

Comment: Thanks @Rathod, only i need to display payment method there, remaining everything is fine

Comment: hi @Rathod, can you help me on that issue please?

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this code

```
       <column name="created_on">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created On</item>
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: yes tried your code, its not working. "Something went wrong " error

Comment: same error again, Grid is not loading

Comment: updated the script please check now

Comment: It should be created_at is it? updated but still same issue, cleared cache and checked it "Bad Request"

Comment: can you please check your model and field name for created at

Comment: yes its created_at is the field name

Comment: what is the data type of created at a field in the database table

Comment: Timestamp is the data type, I am using sales_order_item table

Comment: you have to give data type DATETIME

Comment: Where do i need to change in table? its a default table

Comment: in your installSchema.php file like this ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Cerated At'
                )

Comment: hello nikunj, its a default magento table, i have not created any setup file. why its required to change the code table schema, I hope this is not recommended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95867/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-nikunj).

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a</item>
```

**Instead of**

```
 <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
```

Comment: same error. nothing changed

Comment: @jafarpinjar: after above changes, have you clear cache?

Comment: yes, did the cache flush and checked it, I have one exception,  Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous at

Comment: @jafarpinjar you mean now error is coming diffrent one to previous, right?

Comment: @jafarpinjar: check one more thing your custom column *'created_at'* should not unique key in your custom table.

Comment: yes its not a unique key, more over there is no custom table, I am using sales_order_item table

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You can solve this by using `addFilterToMap()`

> Add this code in your **Collection.php** file

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addFilterToMap(
        'created_at',
        'sales_order_item.created_at'
    );
}
```

**This code is working properly in my module**

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**You can try removing this line**

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
```

Comment: Hello Mohit, used this code, its not working on page load itself error message showing like above, i cleared cache and checked it.

Comment: Try this code 
`<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Created at</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>`

Comment: yes same error again, gird not loading on page load..

Comment: I think some error in xml code,

Comment: can you share your `listing.xml` file ?

Comment: pls check the chat, I have shared it now

Comment: please check the chat..

Comment: @jafarpinjar can you please check my updated answer

Comment: I need to add this code where? Currently i have constructor like below
protected function _construct()
    {
        /* Custom Table Name */
         $this->_init('sales_order_item','item_id');
    }

Comment: there is a Collection.php file in your Resource Model folder

Comment: I have code like above already, How to alter the code like above there, will it work?

Comment: post your code in chat i'll update it

Answer (score 0):

try with below code for UI Component

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

please comment below line

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
```

than update your Collection.php

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addFilterToMap(
        'created_at',
        'sales_order_item.created_at'
    );
}
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: hello @Anas, you mean here? Model/Resource/Products/Grid/Collection.php

Comment: yes, Note : try with your filter attributes. I mention here for just demo which done and working from my side.

Comment: Its not working bro..

Comment: please refer this url - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1724 , may be its very useful to you.