# Magento 2 Add Custom date filter in UI Grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, filter, date, ui-grid

I have created a custom grid for my custom table. It has a created_at column. Now I want to filter the entries by 7 days, 30 days, 90 days. ie, a dropdown with options 7days, 30 days, 90 days.  How do I do it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280834/date-range-filter-not-working-in-custom-grid-magento-2/282096 -- Try this

Comment: @AmiyoGhosh it is talking about date range